# rdd of DataFrame could not change partition number in Spark Structured Streaming python

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I have following code of pyspark in Spark Structured Streaming to get dataFrame from Redis

```
def process(stream_batch, batch_id):
    stream_batch.persist()
    length = stream_batch.count()

    record_rdd = stream_batch.rdd.map(lambda x: b_to_ndarray(x['data']))
    # b_to_ndarray is a single thread method to convert bytes in Redis to ndarray

    record_rdd = record_rdd.coalesce(4) # does not work

    print(record_rdd.getNumPartitions()) # output 1
    # some other code
```

Why? How to fix it? The code in main is

```
loadedDf = spark.readStream.format('redis')...
query = loadedDf.writeStream \
    .foreachBatch(process).start()
query.awaitTermination()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the partitionNum is 1 at the first place, `coalesce` operation does not allow to generate fewer partitions. So no matter how you call it, it would be 1 partition. Unless you use `repartition`